# I'm trying to conver this Web form app to my MVC app, full newbie here

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm trying to conver this Webform app to MVC app

How can I access my Listbox in view to my controller?

I'm a total newbie

Here is the Webform:

```
protected void btnPrintToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Queue<int> tokenQueue = (Queue<int>)Session["TokenQueue"];
        lblStatus.Text = "There are" + tokenQueue.Count.ToString()+
        " customers before you in the queue;

        if (Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] == null)
            Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = 0;
        }
        int nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = (int)Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] + 1;
        Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = nextTokenNumberTobeIssued;
        tokenQueue.Enqueue(nextTokenNumberTobeIssued);
        foreach(int token in tokenQueue)
        listTokens.Item.Clear();
        {
            listTokens.Items.Add(token.ToString());
        }
}
```

Here is my MVC App:

```
    public ActionResult PrintToken()
    {
        Queue<int> tokenQueue = (Queue<int>)Session["TokenQueue"];

        if (Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] == null)
        {
            Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = 0;
        }

        int nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = (int)Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] + 1;
        Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = nextTokenNumberTobeIssued;

        tokenQueue.Enqueue(nextTokenNumberTobeIssued);

        foreach(int token in tokenQueue)
        {
            listTokens.Items.Add(token.ToString());
        }

        return View();
    }
```

It almost have the same view but I don't know how to access my view in MVC like in webforms like "lblStatus.Txt"

Comment: Try doing it without `Session[]`. You are still thinking in WebForms style, that won't work. You need a ViewModel to pass: `return View(myViewModel);`

Comment: can you show me how is that? for please im a newbie i dont quite understand the difference yet

Comment: @HenkHolterman i'm trying to do this in mvc
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIs7ZsMCUWA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MVC you don't directly interact with HTML elements instead supply a view model (alternatively you can use the [ViewBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)) and use [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) to dynamically render the view.

**Here are the steps needed to add a view model to your `PrintToken()` action and render your message:**

**Step 1)** Create a view model that represents all the dynamic values you want to display on the view:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
  public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 2)** Instantiate an instance of your view model, populate your properties and return with the view:

```
public ActionResult PrintToken()
{
    // Create instance of your view model
    var viewModel = new SampleViewModel();

    // Somewhere within your code set the StatusMessage
    viewModel.StatusMessage =  $"There are {tokenQueue.Count.ToString()} customers before you in the queue";

    // Return the view model with the view
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Step 3)** Specify the view model within your view then render the property:

```
<!-- Declare the model on the very top (first line) of your view -->
<!-- Note: This should be the full path including namespace -->
@model SampleViewModel

<!-- Render the property from the view-->
<p>@Model.StatusMessage</p>
```

Comment: going to try this 1

Comment: thankyou man for your answer, I think this is what i'm looking for, I just wanna make this webform app to asp.net any suggestions? 
youtube.com/watch?v=SIs7ZsMCUWA

Comment: @CarloToribio This is a great opportunity to learn MVC, you can do it! Once you have a working MVC version try to replace Session with a more efficient and scalable persistence option.

Answer (score 0):

you can save data in ViewModel and pass it to view via Controller, as referenced below

```
public ActionResult PrintToken()
{
      PrintViewModel print = new PrintViewModel();

    return View(print);
}

PrintToken.cshtml
@model  SampleMVC.Models.PrintViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PrintToken";
}

<h2>PrintToken</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag or ViewData to store message as your requirement

```
public ActionResult PrintToken()
    {
        Queue<int> tokenQueue = (Queue<int>)Session["TokenQueue"];

       ViewBag.StatusText = "There are" + tokenQueue.Count.ToString()+
        " customers before you in the queue;

        if (Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] == null)
        {
            Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = 0;
        }

        int nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = (int)Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] + 1;
        Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = nextTokenNumberTobeIssued;

        tokenQueue.Enqueue(nextTokenNumberTobeIssued);

        foreach(int token in tokenQueue)
        {
            listTokens.Items.Add(token.ToString());
        }

        return View();
    }
```

In your cshtml file

```
<label>@ViewBag.StatusText</label>
```

You also can create your ViewModel as

```
class PrintTokenViewModel{
     public List<string> listTokens{get;set;}
     public string StatusText{get;set;}
}
```

**Other solution: use ViewModel to stored data**

In controller

```
public ActionResult PrintToken()
 {
     var model = new PrintTokenViewModel();
     //handle assign here
     return View(model);
}
```

In View cshtml

```
@model PrintTokenViewModel

<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model.ListTokens){
   <li>@item</li>
}
</ul>

<label>@Model.StatusText</label>
```

Comment: You can use your old class as model or create new view model that map with your database fields

Comment: is this possible.
sample:

in my 1st page i'll have people enter their name and when they click confirm they'll be given a number then ill enqueue them.


then in my 2nd page which is the page of the agent who will call the people when they click next it will dequeue from database?

im building a queue management system.

Comment: You should use entity framework database first for your case

Comment: how can I enqueue them right after they fill up their name and auto generate a number for them then save to the database